# Processing - how to remove image after collision?

Tags: java, image, processing, collision

I'm new to Processing, and I'm making a game where a sprite moves back and forth, and when it collides with the wall (xvalue = 10) it will lose a life. I have 3 hearts in the top corner and when the sprite collides with the wall I want it to remove a heart so it will only display how many lives you have left. How would I remove an image (the heart)?

Here's some code:

```
void loadStuff() {
image(panda, pandaX, pandaY, 80, 112);
image(heart1, 1250, 20, 100, 100);
image(heart2, 1350, 20, 100, 100);
image(heart3, 1450, 20, 100, 100);
if (pandaX<=10) {
  //heart1=null;

//for (int l=0; l<=life; l++) {
//  xCoord = xCoord - 100;  
//  yCoord = yCoord - 100;
//  image(heart1, 0,0,0,0);
//}
}
}

void keyPressed() {
      if (key==CODED) {
        if (keyCode==LEFT) {
        pandaX = pandaX-20;
      }
      if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
        pandaX = pandaX+20;
      }
     if (pandaX<=10) {
       pandaX=10;
       //lives.remove(0);
       //image(heart1,1500, 500); //makes another heart
       //heart1.clear();
       //heart1 = null;
     }
     if (pandaX>=1500) {
       pandaX=1500;
     }
    }

  }
```

I tried a few things to make the heart image disappear - which didn't work. I tried making a for loop which would set all the coordinates to 0, I tried removing the first image from an array I made at the very top of the program, and I tried clearing it - all of which didn't work.

Any input would be greatly appreciated as to how I can remove a heart when the sprite collides into the wall (x=10). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could do that. Need to see more code.

But in general everything you want to draw in **Processing** goes into *draw()* method that runs indefinitely. At the beginning of the method it's a good practice to clear the canvas then you simply draw everything. You could just choose not to draw the heart.

Here is a very simple example. This application draws an image in the screen. After you press any key the image is not drawn anymore.

```
PImage img;
boolean canDraw = true;


void setup() {  // setup() runs once
  size(800, 600);
  frameRate(30);
  loadStuff();
}

void loadStuff() {
  img = loadImage("myImage.png");
}

void draw() {

  background(204); // clears the screen
  if(canDraw) {
      image(img, 0, 0);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  canDraw = false;
}
```